# Avoid repeating so much code on similar task for jquery buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a very simple pop up where I can choose from 8 types of content, all using the same format. It works by clicking on hidden `div`s that show on hover on the top section, of course as you can see I came up with a very long and large code for something that can probably be done with  much less bolts and wires.

Since it's a lot of lines I pasted all this in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsaq2/1/)

Is there a way to make this lighter?

> ***SOLVED... Yeees!***

Thanks to all... here is the final script: [jsFiddle Final](http://jsfiddle.net/TQzXp/47/) in case someone else has the same difficulty

Comment: Why don't you define a function that you pass in any needed variables and sue a reference to the jquery object and perform any actions necessary

Comment: @HolaSoyEduFelizNavidad What about an answer?

Comment: +1 for wanting to write more elegant code.

Comment: @11684 I was asking why he can't use a function, but I think that probably there is a reason for it.

Comment: Of course, writing more elegant code sounds like a codereview task rather than an SO one...

Comment: Its interesting, thanks for the suggestion but I'm quite new to jquery.
I tried putting in single function but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three things you could do to end up with less code:

- Use the hover shortcut
- Use anonymous functions
- Use a parameterized function

First, jQuery has the [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method to replace mouseover/mouseout behavior:

```
$('#scrollbtnR8').bind('mouseover', R8);
$('#scrollbtnR8').bind('mouseout', R8b);
```

Can be replaced as

```
$('#scrollbtnR8').hover(R8, R8b);
```

That's just a little less code though :)

---

Second, you are now defining a function for each eventhandler but you are only using these functions once. If you only use them once, you could create anonymous functions like this:

```
$('#scrollbtnR1').bind('click', esta1);
```

becomes

```
$('#scrollbtnR1').click(function() { 
    $("#scrollcontrol").animate({"left":-240},500, "swing", null);
});
```

---

Finally, you can use a function to encapsulate the common parts of the code and pass the changing parts as parameters.

You could implement it like this:

```
<div id="scrollcontrol" animate="swing" swingLeft="-240">

$('div[animate='swing']').click(function() { 
    $(this).animate({"left": $(this).attr("swingLeft")}, 500, "swing", null);
});
```

The "div" selector uses the [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/). You could also assign a class to all "animate" divs and select them using the class selector: `$("div.animate")` which would select all `<div class="animate">`.

What happens here is:

- Select all divs that have the value 'swing' for the animate attribute.
- Call jQuery swing animate BUT use `$(this).attr("swingLeft")` as the left property.

[`attr("wingLeft")`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) gets the value for the swingLeft property as defined in your HTML markup.

I stopped looking at your code at this point, the key is: Look at the code to be executed and see if you notice a pattern, something that you can generalize. You could then perhaps simplify the code further.
Also worth noting: Some people don't like adding properties like "animate", "swingLeft" etc to the HTML. **Update** As per pimvdb's comment, you can use the [jQuery data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to be a bit 'cleaner'.

The code could look like this then:

```
<div id="scrollcontrol" class="swing" data-swingLeft="-240">

$('.swing').click(function() { 
    $(this).animate({"left": $(this).data("swingLeft")}, 500, "swing", null);
});
```

Comment: Two little things: Given that the OP is using jQuery 1.8, he may want to use `.on` instead of the deprecated `.bind`. Second, for custom attributes you ought to use `data-swingLeft` (and optionally `.data("swingLeft")`).

Comment: `.on` is the replacement for `.live` not for `.bind`. Using [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) is a good idea though.

Comment: No, `.on` is unified - it supersedes `.bind`, `.live` and `.delegate`.

Comment: I'm not understanding,  it's  just getting to complicated... To many .on .bind .data deprecated stuff for a novice like me.
Please tell me If what I have right now works for the next 2 years like it is until I learn proper jquery coding :)
It's all grate help from you guys but I'm not grasping or getting it, it's just,  and I don´t want to take much more of your time. I won't stop I promise I'll keep following your advice until I get it to work :) 
Thank's

Comment: @SamRamSan: pimvdb pointed out that `.bind("click", ...` should no longer be used in jQuery 1.8. The new function is called `.on("click", ...)`. In your case you can simply use `.click(...)` however. I've updated my code to use .click directly.

Comment: Why would I put the swing left inside de scrollcontrol, what if the next button needs to move it to -480??? I tried at the beginning to put the left and right buttons outside the estacion div but that was the original problem I had.
So there is no simple way of doing this than??

Comment: Thanks for the help heres the final code [jsFiddle Final](http://jsfiddle.net/TQzXp/47/) You've been of tremendous help

Comment: Yes you can! You've used the anonymous functions now and reduced the amount of code but it can even simpler! I saw that I added the `data-swingLeft="-240"` to the "scrollcontrol" but in fact you have to add the property to each clickable div: `<div class="scrollbutton" id="scrollbtnL1" data-swingleft="0" /> ... <div class="scrollbutton" id=".scrollbtnR1" data-swingleft="-240">` and then do: `$(".scrollbutton").click(function() { $("#scrollcontrol").animate({"left": $(this).data("swingleft") },"fast","swing", null);`. Like this you only have the "animate" function once!

Answer (score 1):

Refactor out all of the repeated behavior into a function and then pass the different pieces in as parameters, e.g. this:

```
function esta1(event) {
    $("#scrollcontrol").animate({"left":-240},500, "swing", null);
}
function esta2(event) {
    $("#scrollcontrol").animate({"left":0},500, "swing", null);
}
...
$('#scrollbtnR1').bind('click', esta1);
$('#scrollbtnL2').bind('click', esta2);
```

Becomes this:

```
function functionName(event, left) {
    $("#scrollcontrol").animate({"left": left},500, "swing", null);
}
$('#scrollbtnR1').bind('click', function (e) {
    functionName(e, -240);
});
$('#scrollbtnL2').bind('click', function (e) {
    functionName(e, 0);
});
```

Continue this refactoring process until you're left with a single generic function, and everything else passes parameters to that function.

If you find your parameter list getting long and unweildy, consider passing a parameter object instead:

```
function functionName(event, params) {
    $("#scrollcontrol").animate({"left": params.left}, 
        params.duration, 
        params.animation, null);
}
$('#scrollbtnR1').bind('click', function (e) {
    functionName(e, { left: -240, duration: 500, animation: "swing" });
});
```

Comment: `$("#scrollcontrol")` should be a passed as `$(this)` or by using `e.target`?

Comment: @SamRamSan when binding an event handler through jquery, the first parameter is always the `Event` object. Most people name this parameter `e` so it does not shadow the global `window.event` object. the `target` property of the `Event` object is the element that is the target of the event, i.e. the DOM element that was clicked.

Comment: I tried but nothing moves now, and when I got it to move it only moved once to the left and that was it...

Comment: @SamRamSan post a fiddle of your new attempt as an edit to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the help heres the final code [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TQzXp/47/) Final. Thanks alot for all your excelente help

Answer (score 1):

For a start, stop referencing everything with IDs. [Use classes, like this](http://jsfiddle.net/gsaq2/2/):

```
$('.scrollbtn').hover(function(){
         $(this).css("opacity","0")
             .animate({"opacity":1},500, "linear");
    }, function() {
        $(this).css("opacity","1")
             .animate({"opacity":0},500, "linear");
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help heres the final code [jsFiddle Final](http://jsfiddle.net/TQzXp/47/)